# Wordpress rename page issue

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am currently working on a new website and there is a tiny problem with renaming one of the pages for the website, so I have a page called https://website.com/studio-hire-2/ and I want to rename it to .../studio-hire/ but unfortunately I can't do that.

So I figured out that this must be because this page already exists, and yes it does! So I went on to look for it among other pages in the dashboard and could not find it. I've looked everywhere among other pages, drafts, bin... its just not there. I have clicked and checked every single one of them. Maybe I am missing something, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Try visiting /studio-hire/ on your website and see what appears?

Comment: Yes, done that too. Its an actual page that exists on the website.

Comment: Then to edit it, just visit it while logged into the dashboard. Aside from that, what is your question?

Comment: Well my question is how to remove a page that is not listed in WP dashboard pages section. sorry. I don't want to edit it, i need to remove it. Because I want to rename a new page

Comment: Bear in mind the slug could be a: category, post, or page - anything that needs its own URL.

Comment: I've done a small check too. I have got 0 posts, and few categories that doesn't contain anything